# Python requests_Query_String_Multiple_Values

Tags: python-requests, query-string

I am trying to request REST API  as below
querystring = {"severity":'medium'}

headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

Question:I want to get some data with multiple severity values in query string. As of now I can pass only a single value.After trying querystring = {"severity":['medium','high']} , got only the medium severity events.
Help please.

Comment: The response returned depends on the rest API implementation. Are you using some public API? If not, it could be an backend issue, you can ask the backend folks to check.

Comment: I need to try that.Thank you.